# Convert Countif to VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the following functions into my (Excel 2010) workbook:

```
    Function Ifs4Count(r As Range, v As String, r2 As Range, v2 As String)
    Ifs4Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(r, v, r2, v2)
    End Function

    Function Ifs6Count(r As Range, v As String, r2 As Range, v2 As String, r3 As Range, v3 As String)
    Ifs6Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(r, v, r2, v2, r3, v3)
    End Function

    Function Ifs8Count(r As Range, v As String, r2 As Range, v2 As String, r3 As Range, v3 As String, r4 As Range, v4 As String)
    Ifs8Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(r, v, r2, v2, r3, v3, r4, v4)
    End Function

    Function ifcount(r As Range, v As String)
    ifcount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r, v)
    End Function
```

These are used in various subs which return values based on which check boxes are checked, such as:

```
If RatchetSizeComboBox.Enabled = False And EndCap2ComboBox.Enabled = False Then
            NumberOOC2TextBox.value = Ifs4Count(rCOMMENTS, "SEND TO CAL", _
                rBRAND, BrandComboBox.value) 'Only Brand
        ElseIf RatchetSizeComboBox.Enabled = False And EndCap2ComboBox.Enabled = True Then
            NumberOOC2TextBox.value = Ifs6Count(rCOMMENTS, "SEND TO CAL", _
                rBRAND, BrandComboBox.value, _
                rCAP, EndCap2ComboBox.value) 'Brand and End Cap
        ElseIf RatchetSizeComboBox.Enabled = True And EndCap2ComboBox.Enabled = False Then
            NumberOOC2TextBox.value = Ifs6Count(rCOMMENTS, "SEND TO CAL", _
                rBRAND, BrandComboBox.value, _
                rRATCHET, RatchetSizeComboBox.value) 'Brand and Size
        Else
            NumberOOC2TextBox.value = Ifs8Count(rCOMMENTS, "SEND TO CAL", _
                rBRAND, BrandComboBox.value, _
                rRATCHET, RatchetSizeComboBox.value, _
                rCAP, EndCap2ComboBox.value) 'Brand, Size and End Cap
        End If
```

I figure there has to be a way to use a for loop so I don't have to use all these different functions each time I need to do an ifcount with a different number of variables, but I'm not very experienced with VBA, so I'm hoping I could get some help. How can I convert this so I'm not using a worksheet function, but rather actual VBA? Any help is appreciated.

After trying out some test code I thought I had it, but now with:

```
Function IfsCount(r As Range, v As String, Optional r2 As Range, Optional v2 As String, Optional r3 As Range, Optional v3 As String, Optional r4 As Range, Optional v4 As String)
    IfsCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(r, v, [r2], [v2], [r3], [v3], [r4], [v4])
End Function
```

I'm getting an invalid call or procedure. Are the brackets not the correct way to mark as optional?

Final code slightly modified from Dirk's answer (it wasn't evaluating each variable if it went past v2). I seem to fail at adding code to this website, so basically what I did was create a new str variable for each "If Len" statement and then changed the evaluation to read:

```
IfsCount = Evaluate("COUNTIFS('" & r.Parent.Name & "'!" & r.Address & ",""" & v & """" & str & str2 & str3 & ")")
```

Thanks for everyone's suggestions!

Comment: what you are looking for is probably `ParamArray a() As Variant` to enter an unknown amount of variables... or `IfsCount(r As Range, v As String, Optional r2 As Range, Optional v2 As String, Optional...)` to be able to skip parameter... or directly use `Application.CountIfs`

Comment: I was about to say the nature of this question is really how to make a passed parameter optional.

Comment: Thanks guys, I had tried this before with the functions but apparently I was doing it wrong... I didn't have brackets around the optionals in the application line, which threw errors. Seems to be working now, thanks. I would still like to move more away from worksheet functions (most of my code started off as this type, and as I've learned better ways to do things I've been using it a lot less). Thanks again!

Comment: sometimes application function is the way to go because the built in excel function is very efficient.  SOMETIMES

Comment: Well I thought I had it working. Added my new line to the original post, I must still be doing something wrong. I did change all references to the various original functions to call the new one instead.

Comment: since your function is one line long and all it is doing is calling a function, why not just call the application function directly?  why ad the intermediate step?

Comment: The counifs application function can already deal with multiple arguments which you were already supplying uniquely to each of your functions calls.

Comment: Trying to use "Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs" without defining the arguments throws "Compile error: Argument not optional"... Unless you meant something else?

Comment: why not skip out the whole `Function IfsCount(...` part and instead of calling `IfsCount` later on directly call every time `Application.CountIfs(...`? (I think that was his question)

Comment: exactly dirk, and then you dont need to worry about passing enough variables,  just pass them as need from the body of your sub using application.worksheetfunction call, and forget the whole UDF.

Comment: Well if that is the best way to do it then ok, it was just too cluttered for me to read when I first wrote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying, is not possible! It is simply the **vba-syntax** which doesn't support something like that...

Also having optional parameters which are not variant it is not possible to detect if they where omitted or not.  The only way to do what you are trying may be the evaluate function:

```
Function IfsCount(r As Range, v As String, Optional r2 As Range, Optional v2 As String, Optional r3 As Range, Optional v3 As String, Optional r4 As Range, Optional v4 As String)
  Dim str As String
  If Len(v2) Then str = ",'" & r2.Parent.Name & "'!" & r2.Address & ",""" & v2 & """"
  If Len(v3) Then str = ",'" & r3.Parent.Name & "'!" & r3.Address & ",""" & v3 & """"
  If Len(v4) Then str = ",'" & r4.Parent.Name & "'!" & r4.Address & ",""" & v4 & """"
  IfsCount = Evaluate("COUNTIFS('" & r.Parent.Name & "'!" & r.Address & ",""" & v & """" & str & ")")
End Function
```

Comment: I will toy around with this when I get back to my computer, this may be the way to at least combine the functions. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: This seems to be working. It may not be much shorter than the way I had it before, but it's definitely cleaner and easier to read, I like having it all in one function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
If RatchetSizeComboBox.Enabled = False And EndCap2ComboBox.Enabled = False Then
    NumberOOC2TextBox.value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rCOMMENTS, "SEND TO CAL", rBRAND, BrandComboBox.value) 'Only Brand
ElseIf RatchetSizeComboBox.Enabled = False And EndCap2ComboBox.Enabled = True Then
    NumberOOC2TextBox.value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rCOMMENTS, "SEND TO CAL", rBRAND, BrandComboBox.value, rCAP, EndCap2ComboBox.value) 'Brand and End Cap
ElseIf RatchetSizeComboBox.Enabled = True And EndCap2ComboBox.Enabled = False Then
    NumberOOC2TextBox.value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rCOMMENTS, "SEND TO CAL", rBRAND, BrandComboBox.value, rRATCHET, RatchetSizeComboBox.value) 'Brand and Size
Else
    NumberOOC2TextBox.value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rCOMMENTS, "SEND TO CAL", rBRAND, BrandComboBox.value, rRATCHET, RatchetSizeComboBox.value, rCAP, EndCap2ComboBox.value) 'Brand, Size and End Cap
End If
```

Skip the whole user function and call directly from the body of your if statement.  You should also declare what worksheet your are working with I believe.

Comment: Oh, I did that before and it worked fine, I just wanted to make it cleaner and easier to read, and possibly learn something for other projects. My search functions all used to be index/match based until I learned how to write a proper find sub, so I'm just trying to do the same with other code.

Answer (score 0):

you could simply go like this

```
Dim sRATCHET As String, sCAP As String

sRATCHET = IIf(RatchetSizeComboBox.Enabled, RatchetSizeComboBox.Value, "*")
sCAP = IIf(EndCap2ComboBox.Enabled, EndCap2ComboBox.Value, "*")

NumberOOC2TextBox.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rCOMMENTS, "SEND TO CAL", _
                                                                  rBRAND, BrandComboBox.Value, _
                                                                  rRATCHET, sRATCHET, _
                                                                  rCAP, sCAP)
```